# How to send email on specific time using php?

Tags: php, email, date

HI i am developing a website. In this i am having one reminder form. One the user gave the details, the reminder should go daily from the specific date. For example if the user wants reminder from 23.08.13 means, reminder should go from 23.08.13 till 27.08.13. This five times. Is it possible to do it without database connection? Can anyone help me to solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a cronjob which will execute a php-script. the script will check what date/time it is and if there are recipients for the reminder-mails it will send out mails.

Comment: i never heard about this cron job. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I reviewed cron job. It will run the php file automatically based on the time which we set in the control panel. Am i right? But my doubt is, if the user setting the reminder today, and as per the reminder we need to send the reminder mail from 23.08.13 to till 27.08.13. How is it possible without database connection. Could you please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

every web hosting allows you to create planned actions - Crony, which are starts  in defined time.

Comment: i never heard about this crony. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I reviewed cron job. It will run the php file automatically based on the time which we set in the control panel. Am i right? But my doubt is, if the user setting the reminder today, and as per the reminder we need to send the reminder mail from 23.08.13 to till 27.08.13. How is it possible without database connection. Could you please explain me?